Material UI Megamenu Slide transition locking out further interaction
I tried to implement a slide transition for my megamenu I created using Material UI. However, when I created it and tested it out, I was locked out of any further interaction with the page after I closed the Megamenu.
const Header = () => {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = useState(null);
  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

(/*these were the functions I created, below you will find the actual megamenu*/)
 <Menu
                  id="Company-options"
                  anchorEl={anchorEl}
                  open={open}
                  onClose={handleClose}
                  TransitionComponent={(props) => (
                    <Slide direction='down' unmountOnExit={true} {...props} />
                  )}
                  MenuListProps={{
                    'aria-labelledby': 'Company-Button',
                  }}
                  PaperProps={{
                    sx: {
                      width: "100vw", 
                      height: "50%",
                      backgroundColor: '#f4f4f4',
                      position: "absolute",
                      marginTop: '2px',
                      zIndex: 1300,   
                    }
                  }}
                >

`
Above, you will see I tried to add unmountOnExit to see if that removed the locked out state. It still had the same result. I also attempted to change out the width and the height, or by removing position absolute, but that too did not do anything. Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks!

In order to passing props to TransitionComponent, you have to use TransitionProps.
<Menu
    // ...
    TransitionComponent={Slide}
    TransitionProps={{
        direction: 'down',
        unmountOnExit: true,
    }}
    // ...
>
    {/* ... */}
</Menu>

Reference: https://mui.com/material-ui/api/popover/#popover-prop-TransitionProps

I see, thanks a lot! I really appreciate it!
